# Testing Google authenticated app in Crostini

Tags: php, authentication, google-app-engine, chromebook

I'm running php7.3 and apache2 on my chromebook linux - it browses fine via penguin.linux.test - but after successfully popping up the google authentication dialog, the redirect back never seems to happen. It just sits there. No error - I had an error but added penguin.linux.test to the allowable javascript origins on the google cloud console. It works fine if I deploy to GAE but I  would like to do local testing.

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: I have used the minimal example provided by Google as follows...